# How to avoid exception while loading cpp library in Java?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm working on Java. I'm trying to load an cpp shared library in Java class using following code call:

```
System.loadLibrary("libraryName");
```

But the loading cpp library containing some undefined symbols itself.
So when i tried to compile the Java class then it throws and an exception as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:libraryName.so:
libraryName.so: undefined symbol: ...
```

do we have any option to load cpp library successfully even if it contains undefined symbols?

Comment: why do you want to load it if it contains problems?

Comment: As it a `.so` library I assume it's Unix.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes it is linux

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but in this case this symbol/method/fields was required to load the library.  In some cases, missing symbols are not discovered until the program is running. ;)

The only way to get this library to load is to provide a library with the symbol required.

Comment: ya i know the all undefined symbols. How can i use them to load library successfully?

Comment: Create a dummy library which defines those symbols and give it the expected library name. if you use `ldd libraryName.so` it should tell you what it expects to load and what is missing.  If every library is there, you can pre-load the library with the dummy symbols.